# How to create a bean definition only if the bean was not loaded before?

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I'm using Hibernate and Mybatis for the Dao layer, altogether with Spring 3. All the beans configurations are through XML. The integration between Hibernate and Mybatis doesn't have any problem when we declare these beans in the same XML file. I tried to decouple them in different files and a problem raised on integration tests, since we cannot execute the tests for MyBatis since it lacks for `transactionManager` bean. When the configuration was in a single file, this was no problem because we have this:

```xml
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <!-- 
        sessionFactory bean is provided by Hibernate configuration.
        Problem: when decoupling the configuration, there's no
        transactionManager bean and the tests fail.
    -->
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

After splitting the configuration, I solved this problem in the test environment by redefining the `transactionManager` bean in the MyBatis config xml.

```xml
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

But now I have a unit test were both Hibernate and Mybatis are required. How can I avoid the creation of `transactionManager` defined in MyBatis configuration to only use `transactionManager` defined in Hibernate configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I would split the `transactionManager` bean definition into a third file.  So you would load two files (hibernate + transactionManager or iBatis + transactionManager) or three files ( hibernate +  iBatis + transactionManager) as needed. The `transactionManager` can also be declared in a "common" spring file that is always imported.  This is the approach I've used in the past.  I've seen posts on how to override Spring bean definitions, but most people recommend against it.